# `get_ipython` not in globals if importing from file?

Tags: python, namespaces, global-variables

Start an ipython console and run

```py
'get_ipython' in globals()
```

This will return `True`.

Now consider instead a file `package.py` with the following content:

```py
print('get_ipython' in globals())
   
print(get_ipython())
```

and run

```
import package
```

This will return

```
False
<IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x7f33aafdbe20>
```

How is that possible? `globals` should be global! Or what else am I missing?

Comment: The function should be available on the `__builtin__` module - `hasattr(__builtin__, 'get_ipython')`

Comment: @IainShelvington That aslo work directly in the console, but importing from a file that would return a `NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined`

Comment: My mistake, you need to import the builtins module itself - `import builtins; print(hasattr(builtins, 'get_ipython'))`

Comment: You're right that works: but why is that? Why isn't get_ipython included in globals when importing? While it is when starting up a python session?